# ivh-treeview styling and "onLeafClick()"

Tags: css, angularjs, treeview

I'm in trouble with styling my html menu that is based upon the [ivh-treeview](https://github.com/iVantage/angular-ivh-treeview).
I cannot understand how to style separately parent and child nodes. In my situation there will be no "grandchildren", I just need two-level treeview, here what I've done:

http://plnkr.co/edit/8Ij0MUkTwED9kOQAzYMU?p=preview

```
#mainMenu {
    background-color:black;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding-left: 0;
    width:150px;
}

    #mainMenu .ivh-treeview-twistie {
        display: none;

    }

  /* Parent style ? */
  #mainMenu .ivh-treeview-node-label {
      color: cyan;
      border-bottom:solid;
  }


     /* Children style ? */
    #mainMenu .ivh-treeview-node-leaf {
        color: green;
        border-bottom:solid;
        cursor:pointer;
    }


        #mainMenu .ivh-treeview-node-leaf .ivh-treeview-toggle {
            color: white;
            cursor: pointer;
            border-bottom:none;
        }
```

Although I can apply styles to children, I cannot do that to parent nodes, e.g. I cannot set paddings or margins, also I need to stretch the "click region" of the nodes to 100%, I can't do that neither.

The other question is, how can I make callbacks on leaf clicks, when using no checkboxes? It's pretty simple with checkboxes, but I don't have them and don't want them.

Thank you.